# jquery-datepicker-enable autoclose-when-time is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquerydatetimepicker

I am currently using `jqueryUI datetimepicker`. I would like to get the  `datetimepicker` close automatically once both the date and time is selected. I tried with the following on `onSelect` function. But not sure if it is the best way to solve this problem.

```
  onSelect : function() {
                 var minuteslider = $('.ui_tpicker_minute_slider');
                     if(minuteslider) {
                         minuteslider.change(function() {
                         $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();
                     });
                 }
```

Comment: Is you code working or not?

Comment: Can you tell me which addon you are using for time picker? If you can give me source that will helpful to answer your question

Comment: @Nurzhan : It is working but I am not sure if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I am using the following add-on: https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon